# Codeigniter Dompdf : Call to a member function isHtml5ParserEnabled() on null

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I placed the 'dompdf' @ '/system/libraries/', and create a class file 'Dompdf.php' at the same dir, code as below:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

class CI_Dompdf extends Dompdf {
    /**
     * Set the template from the table config file if it exists
     *
     * @param   array   $config (default: array())
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        log_message('info', 'Dompdf Class Initialized');
    }
}
```

below is part of the controller function which using the dompdf library:

```
public function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE){
    $this->load->library('Dompdf','dompdf');

    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
    if ($stream) {
        $this->dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    } else {
        return $this->dompdf->output();
    }
}
```

but I get the error below:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isHtml5ParserEnabled() on null in /home/mysite/public_html/ci/system/libraries/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php on line 492
```

I'd checked the function does exists in 'dompdf/src/Options.php'.

I have no idea how to solve it.

My dev env:

- Codeigniter 3.0.6
- Dompdf 0.7.0

Thanks.

**UPDATE** Found error occurred due to not call **Dompdf** constructor, correct code as below:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class CI_Dompdf extends Dompdf {

    /**
     *
     * @param   array   $config (default: array())
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        parent::__construct($config);

        log_message('info', 'Dompdf Class Initialized');
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not about function exists or not. It says that object by which `isHtml5ParserEnabled ()` is getting called is NULL.

Comment: I'm using all default & follow with the sample code, no idea how can make it work. I'd checked the **Dompdf** class constructor will auto new the **Options** object.